# Magento 2: Mix & Match Product with Buy More Get Discount

Tags: magento2, product, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have 10 different simple products.

- If a customer buys any of 2 (among 10) then it will be 5$ price discount.
- If a customer buys any of 3 (among 10) then it will be 10$ price discount.

So among 10 products on basis of Quantity user gets the discount.

Tier pricing is only used for that product. But I have to do same for X products.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Discard subsequent rules' and create rules with different priority.

This is the best way to do this action without any code customization.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this extension that handles this in Magento 2 nexct to a lot of other features that might come in handy regarding Tier Pricing.

https://www.best4mage.com/configurable-products-and-tier-prices-for-magento-2.html